# List Collection Filtering using Where condition giving null values

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I am getting the Values from DataBase View Table using the EDM
Query as IList Type.

it is giving some Collection of Elements.

From this collection, i am tring
to filter the data based on One Column but is doesn't giving the
filtered data even though the data is present based on condition   The
query is as like below.

For Getting Data form DataBase   // it is
fetching some collection of data.

```
IList<EFModel.EntityModel.vwGetActiveEmployee> activeEmployeelist = TimeOffService.GetActiveEmployees();
```

Here i want to fileter the data based on Column IsManger(values 1 or 0) 
For that i wrote like

```
IList<EFModel.EntityModel.vwGetActiveEmployee> managerlist = activeEmployeelist.Where(p => p.IsManager == 1).Select(p => p) as IList<EFModel.EntityModel.vwGetActiveEmployee>;
```

But here the Managerlist showing null values.   When i filter the data
using below

```
 var emplistVar = activeEmployeelist.Where(p => p.IsManager.Equals(1)).Select(p => p);
```

it showing the some collection of data with "var" type but if i give
Class type it showing null.   What is the reason here, This data is
taken from database View Data.

Comment: From my limited understanding, it is due to lazy-loading. i.e. the query is run only when you access an element or traverse using `foreach` or `for` over the return value. The idea is to not fetch the results as soon as the statement is executed. Lookup lazy-loading to understand this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code (reformatted to avoid scrolling):

```
IList<EFModel.EntityModel.vwGetActiveEmployee> managerlist 
     = activeEmployeelist.Where(p => p.IsManager == 1)
                         .Select(p => p)
       as IList<EFModel.EntityModel.vwGetActiveEmployee>;
```

... will *always* give `managerlist` as a `null`, as `Select` doesn't return an `IList<T>` in any implementation I've ever seen. I suspect you want:

```
IList<vwGetActiveEmployee> managerlist =
    activeEmployeelist.Where(p => p.IsManager == 1)
                      .ToList();
```

Note that unless you're *deliberately* performing a reference type conversion which can validly fail (in which case you should usually be checking the result against `null`) you should prefer casts instead of `as`. If you'd used a cast here, you'd have seen an exception immediately, because the value returned by `Select` wasn't of the type you were expecting.